# from minio.error import ResponseError ImportError: cannot import name 'ResponseError'

Tags: python, importerror

from minio.error import ResponseError

[image]

I don't know why...Could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you running your minio instance ?

Comment: @MayRestinPeace yes I'm running my minio instance to download something...

Answer (score 0):

I change it to this

`from minio.error import S3Error`

and this can do the same way as the old one

```
python:3.6.9
minio:'7.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

could change minio version:

python3 -m pip uninstall minio

python3 -m pip install minio==6.0.2